# qt minimumSize() returns 0 but in qt designer it is set to non-zero

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwidget, qlabel

There's a custom widget inherited from `QLabel` which is promoted for an advanced functionality.
Its minimumSize (for width and height) is set to 150 in qt designer.

But the calls to `minimumSize.width()`, `minimumSize().height()` in the constructor of the custom widget returns `0` for some reason

```
InventoryItem::InventoryItem(QWidget* parent): QLabel(parent)
{
    qDebug() << minimumSize().width(); // 0 ???
    qDebug() << minimumSize().height(); // 0 ???
}
```

However, from the mainwindow constructor it returns correct values (150, 150)
by calling `ui->thatWidget->minimumSize().width(); // 150`, ... and same for height

Also there are vertical and horizontal layouts of the widgets on the mainwindow.

I'm just not that familiar with GUI programming in QT.

What's happening there ??

How to get correct values from the custom widget ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor of the main window starts with the following line: `ui->setup(this);`. This is a call to the `setup()` function of the *moc* file automatically generated for the main window. This function constructs the *InventoryItem* and THEN sets its minimum size. Seeing is believing, so take a look at the *moc* file in the folder where the project is built. So by calling `ui->thatWidget->minimumSize().width();` later on in the constructor of the main window the expected minimum width of 150 is reported. At the time of the construction of *InventoryItem* however, the minimum size is not yet set, hence calling `qDebug() << minimumSize().width();` in its constructor reports the default value of the minimum width. The [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#minimumSize-prop) for *QWidget* states for the minimum size:

> By default, this property contains a size with zero width and height.

In short, the world still functions, i.e. the behavior you observe is the expected one.